# Модульное тестирование в C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, юнит-тесты, тестирование

Как правильно протестировать Data access layer с помощью `Mock`, а именно репозитории, предоставляющие доступ к базе данных через контекст?

Проблема в том, что каждый репозиторий в качестве аргумента получает `DbContext`. Этот контекст возвращает `Ninject`.

```
public UserRepository(DbContext context)
```

Хотел подсунуть фейковый `DbContext`, но не получается создать объект `DbSet`

```
Mock<DbContext> context = new Mock<DbContext>();
context.Setup(c => c.Set<User>()).Returns( ??? );
```

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал вам прочитать про [Google's unit testing framework](https://github.com/google/googletest).

Comment: @AndreyYanov Google's C++ test framework - это для C++. Какое отношение он имеет к мокингу DBContext в C#?

Comment: @PashaPash смотрел-смотрел и никак не мог понять как его использовать под C#. Возник такой же как у Вас.

Answer (score 0):

Анализ ситуации показал только два выхода из ситуации:

1. Создание БД для тестирования и проведение всех манипуляций над ней. Этот подход почти сразу откинул по личным соображениям - тесты зависят друг от друга.
2. Создание обертки на контекстом и дальнейшее использование через интерфейс обертки:

   ```
   interface IDbRepository 
   {
       DbContext Context { get; }
       IQueryable<MyType> MyTypes { get; }
       // etc.
   }
   ```

И сам wrapper

```
public class DbRepository : IDbRepository
{
    DbContext context;

    public DbRepository(DbContext context)
    {
       this.context = context;
    }

    public DbContext Context { get { return context; } }

    public IQueryable<MyType> MyTypes { get { return context.Set<MyType>(); } }
```

Старый контекст заменяем на интерфейс

> public UserRepository(DbContext context)

```
public UserRepository(IDbRepository repository)
```

И теперь можно тестировать `UserRepository` с помощью Mock

```
Mock<IDbRepository> wrapper = new Mock<IDbRepository>();
wrapper.Setup(c => c.MyTypes).Returns( new [] { new MyType(...) }.AsQueryable() );
```

Сомневаюсь в правильности. Теперь репозитории становятся менее гибкие